# Macbook Pro Retina Mid 2014 Heat and fan confusion

Tags: macbook-pro, temperature

I bought a mid-2014 15inch retina Macbook pro last week. I didn't have much time to work with it as my main machine, but today I had more free time so I did and noticed that after a few hours of work it really gets warm on the bottom and fans don't go on higher RPM to cool it down. (It's almost impossible to hear the fans working without pushing my ears against the back of it)

Wanted to ask people who own this laptop or similar models that is this normal? Is your macbook almost quiet all day?

I installed the smFanControll app and it shows the temperature between 50-55 and fan speed at ~2600RPM, is this normal temperature and fan speed?

Comment: Same thing here. I just purchased my 15 inch retina display 7 days ago. this unit is souped up with all the works I maximised memory to 1 TB and CPU is 2.8 ghz and could turbo boost to 4.0 After using it for a couple of hours, I immediately noticed that it was getting too hot for comfort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this perfectly normal behaviour, 55 is a very reasonable temperature as well. If you start using your device more heavily, like encoding video, playing games, or installing certain software, you should start to notice the fans picking up.